# How to fix the following mapDeep function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to build a **`mapDeep`** function (map recursively down a nested array):

```
mapDeep (array, callback) {
  return array.map(item => {
    if (Array.isArray(Object.values(item)[0])) {
      return mapDeep(Object.values(item)[0])
    } else {
      return callback(Object.values(item)[0])
    }
  })
},

mapDeep(input.schema, field => {
  console.log('field:', field)
})
```

Right now I'm getting the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function`

How to modify the code to fix the function?

[**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/alexcheninfo/pen/LLRpwo?editors=0010)

**Input:**

```
schema: [{
  fields: [{
    (...)
  }, {
    (...)
  }]
}, {
  fields: [{
    (...)
  }]
}]
```

Comment: "*`Object.values(item)[0]`*"? Don't do that. Be explicit about that you mean `item.fields`. Pass the property name as another parameter if you need it to be generic.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the argument on to the recursive call:

```
function mapDeep (array, callback) {
  return array.map(item => {
    if (Array.isArray(Object.values(item)[0])) {
      return mapDeep(Object.values(item)[0], callback)
//                                           ^^^^^^^^
    } else {
      return callback(Object.values(item)[0])
    }
  })
}
```